# How to ensure that one property in object is always true in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have a filter object as shown. Only one filter can be true at a time, By default `unread` is true.
If `read` is set true then other two are false.
If `read` is set false then by default `unread` should be set true.
How to achieve this with calling function `updateFilter(filter,value)` or suggest a better way.

```
var filter = {
unread: true,
read: false,
all: false
}
```

**The Html part:**

```
<div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch">
   <div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch-text"> Unread:</div>
   <span class="gb-switch filter-btn"ng-click="healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.unread = !healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.unread;healthCtrl.notificationFilterChange('unread')" ng-class="{'active':  healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.unread }">
      <div class="gb-switch-handle"></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch">
   <div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch-text"> Read:</div>
   <span class="gb-switch filter-btn"ng-click="healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.read = healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.read;healthCtrl.notificationFilterChange('read')" ng-class="{'active':  healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.read }">
      <div class="gb-switch-handle"></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch">
   <div class="gb-notification-action-top-switch-text"> All:</div>
   <span class="gb-switch filter-btn"ng-click="healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.all = !healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.all;healthCtrl.notificationFilterChange('all')" ng-class="{'active':  healthCtrl.info.noti_filter.all }">
      <div class="gb-switch-handle"></div>
   </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to consider changing the UI?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, Will add a simple checkbox instead.

Comment: OK - just the current UI suggests you can pick none or all of them, which doesn't make sense.  A basic fix would be to use a dropdown with the 3 choices, but a nicer looking one would involve 3 buttons which show the active state - clicking one button turns the others off etc

Comment: if you set `read` to false, and causes `unread` to be false, does this cause `all` to change to false also?

Comment: What your after is something called a radio group, rather than a set of checkbox's.  https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

Comment: @CozyAzure unread should be true if  other properties are false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do it like this:

```js
const filter = {
    unread: false,
    read: true,
    all: false
}

const updateFilter = (keyName, value) => {
  for (let key in filter) {
    filter[key] = (key === keyName) ? value : false;
  }
  if (!Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(filter))) filter.unread = true;
}
  
updateFilter('read', false);
console.log(filter);
```

Comment: This works. It will be helpful for me to learn if you could explain this part of the solution !Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(filter)). Thanks again!

Comment: @Nishanth actualy it just the first thing that came to mind ) - convert values to array and check if it has at least one true inside; You also can write it like this:
```if(!Object.values(filter).includes(true)) filter.unread = true;```

Comment: i doubt  i made best solution. By the way you actualy need pass only keyname to 'updateFilter' function.
See no reason when you should needed to send 'false' or 'true' value, you can just pass keyname and toggle the current value. And than set 'unread' key to 'true' if there is no other true values in object.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick:

```
function updateFilter(filter, target_filter){
    for (var f of Object.keys(filter)){
        filter[f] = false
    }
    filter[target_filter] = true
}
```

The function just iterates over all the properties of the filter and sets them to false, and then sets the target option to true.

So, if you did something like:

```
var filter = {
unread: true,
read: false,
all: false
}

updateFilter(filter, "unread")
```

Your filter would look like:

```
var filter = {
unread: true,
read: false,
all: false
}
```

And `updateFilter(filter, "all")` would get you:

```
var filter = {
unread: false,
read: false,
all: true
}
```

And so on and so forth - you get the idea.

Comment: This doesn't work when i have to set a property to false. also to check if everything is false then make   unread   as true.